# How to find Max value of an alphanumeric field in oracle?

Tags: oracle, max, varchar, alphanumeric

I have the data as below and ID is VARCHAR2 type

**Table Name :EMP**

```
ID    TST_DATE
A035     05/12/2015
BAB0     05/12/2015
701    07/12/2015
81     07/12/2015
```

I used below query to get max of ID group by TST_DATE.

```
SELECT TST_DATE,MAX(ID) from EMP group by TST_DATE;

TST_DATE     MAX(ID)
05/12/2015    BAB0 
07/12/2015    81
```

In the second row it returning 81 instead of 701.

Comment: Of course it does return 81 because `'8'` is bigger than `'701'`

Comment: String are sorted using [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Answer (score 2):

To sort strings that represent (hex) numbers in numeric, rather than lexicographical, order you need to convert them to actual numbers:

```
SELECT TST_DATE, ID, TO_NUMBER(ID, 'XXXXXXXXXX') from EMP
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(ID, 'XXXXXXXXXX');

TST_DATE   ID                TO_NUMBER(ID,'XXXXXXXXXX')
---------- ---- ---------------------------------------
07/12/2015 81                                       129
07/12/2015 701                                     1793
05/12/2015 A035                                   41013
05/12/2015 BAB0                                   47792
```

You can use that numeric form within your `max()` and convert back to a hex string for display:

```
SELECT TST_DATE,
  TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(ID, 'XXXXXXXXXX')), 'XXXXXXXXXX')
from EMP group by TST_DATE;

TST_DATE   TO_CHAR(MAX
---------- -----------
07/12/2015         701
05/12/2015        BAB0
```

With a suitable number of Xs in the format models of course; how many depends on the size of your varchar2 column.

Comment: Getting error ORA-01722 Invalid Number error when executing the query, SELECT TST_DATE, ID, TO_NUMBER(ID, 'XXXXXXXXXX') from EMP
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(ID, 'XXXXXXXXXX');

Comment: @MidhunKrishna - what is the size of the column, and what is the longest value in it? Are any of the values not alphanumeric?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex..The column is a varchar column and its length is 4. The values is mix of alphanumeric and numbers. For example , 001,045,571, A870,B787,81 etc

Comment: @MidhunKrishna - does `SELECT * from EMP WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ID, '^[0-9A-F]*$')` find anything that isn't actually a number?

Comment: Yes Alex..its returning two rows.. with ID values BZB0,DZB0

Comment: @MidhunKrishna - right, those are not hex numbers, so what do you want to do with them? Exclude them from your query? Treat them as if they are specific values? Something else?